# Spark JDBC read API: Determining the number of partitions dynamically for a column of type datetime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, spark-jdbc

I'm trying to read a table from an RDS MySQL instance using PySpark. It's a huge table, hence I want to parallelize the read operation by making use of the partitioning concept. The table doesn't have a numeric column to find the number of partitions. Instead, it has a timestamp column (i.e. datetime type).

I found the lower and upper bounds by retrieving the min and max values of the timestamp column. However, I'm not sure if there's a standard formula to find out the number of partitions dynamically. Here is what I'm doing currently (hardcoding the value for numPartititons parameter):

```
select_sql = "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(columns, table)
partition_info = {'partition_column': 'col1', 
                  'lower_bound': '<result of min(col1)>', 
                  'upper_bound': '<result of max(col1)>', 
                  'num_partitions': '10'}
read_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("driver", driver) \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", select_sql) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("useSSL", False) \
        .option("partitionColumn", partition_info['partition_column']) \
        .option("lowerBound", partition_info['lower_bound'])) \
        .option("upperBound", partition_info['upper_bound'])) \
        .option("numPartitions", partition_info['num_partitions']) \
        .load()
```

Please suggest me a solution/your approach that works. Thanks

Comment: what is the code that you have tried here ?

Comment: I have added the code snippet. Kindly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

How to set `numPartitions` depends on your cluster's definition. There are no right or wrong or automatic settings here. As long as you understand the logic behind `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions`, and probably lots of benchmarking, you can decide what's the right number.

[Pyspark - df.cache().count() taking forever to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477084/pyspark-df-cache-count-taking-forever-to-run/67511760#67511760)

[What is the meaning of partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085238/what-is-the-meaning-of-partitioncolumn-lowerbound-upperbound-numpartitions-pa/41085557#41085557)